# jQuery - set array values to the input with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I was trying to set the array values to the input field named `attachments[]`

I have array stored in js variable `attachArray`

What I have tried is,

```
$('[name="attachments"]').attr('value', attachArray);
```

or

```
$('[name="attachments"]').val(attachArray);
```

But getting empty `attachments` in the controller like this,

```
array(1) { ["attachments"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group ticket-align">
        <label>Attachment</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t-attachment-modal">
                    Browse&hellip; 
             <input type="hidden" name="attachments[]">
         </label>
         <span id="fileList"></span>
         <span class="error" id="error-atachments" style='display: none;'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie Didn't succeed.

Comment: This is an array of what?

Comment: @Stuart  Its an array of strings

Comment: So `$('[name=attachments\\[\\]]').val(attachArray);` OR  `$('input:hidden[name=attachments\\[\\]]').val(attachArray);` will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a hidden input, so

Either:-

```
$('[name=attachments]').val(attachArray);
```

OR

```
$('input:hidden[name=attachments]').val(attachArray);
```

Will work.

Note:- Use the backslashes(***Escape internal brackets with `\\`(no space)***).

Comment: I removed the `[]` from the input name field. And used this `$('[name=attachments]').val(attachArray);`. This workes better than @lumio's solution.

Comment: why the value is: [object Object]

Comment: @huykon225 Even I got the result as [Object Object] saved in the hidden field, but tried below to stored the value as array and get the value as array.


`var elems = [];
elems.push('1');
 elems.push('2');
 elems.push('3');

$('#input_hidden_field').val(JSON.stringify(elems)); //store array

var value = $('#input_hidden_field').val(); //retrieve array
value = JSON.parse(value);`

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand is that you want to spread the content of an JavaScript array to multiple fields that PHP on the other hand interprets as an array.

I changed the inputs from `hidden` to `text` just to make it a little bit more clear and so you can see how the values do look like. Don't forget to undo this in your code.

```js
const attachArray = [
  'val1',
  'val2',
];
const attachments = $('[name="attachments[]"]');
for ( let i = 0; i < attachments.length; i += 1 ) {
  $( attachments[ i ] ).val( attachArray[ i ] );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group ticket-align">
        <label>Attachment</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t-attachment-modal">
                    Browse&hellip; <br>
             <input type="text" name="attachments[]"><br>
             <input type="text" name="attachments[]">
         </label>
         <span id="fileList"></span>
         <span class="error" id="error-atachments" style='display: none;'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is a lot of code to do. I think it might be easier to send the array as JSON and use PHPs [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it back into an array, like so:

```js
const attachArray = [
  'val1',
  'val2',
];
$('[name="attachments"]').val( JSON.stringify( attachArray ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group ticket-align">
        <label>Attachment</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t-attachment-modal">
                    Browse&hellip; <br>
             <input type="text" name="attachments">
         </label>
         <span id="fileList"></span>
         <span class="error" id="error-atachments" style='display: none;'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And do something like

```
$attachments = json_decode( $_POST[ 'attachments' ] );
```

Comment: I know. I changed it to make it more clear what happens

Comment: Thanks. This solution is more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

you have input field with name as `attachments[]` so try this

```
$('[name="attachments[]"]').val(attachArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention id to a hidden field and you are sending array through the form so declare hidden field name with square brackets like below.

```
<input type="text" name="attachments[]" id="attachments">
```

And bind your array with the jquery `val()` method.

```
$('#attachments').val(attachArray);
```

For Future Reference :-)